# Returning an Object's method names

Tags: java, methods

I have the ability to run code that lets me make calculations and/or get variable information from a program. However I do not have access to the base code, and wondering if there is a way to print out all the methods an Object has available (public)?

Example the Class Shape, with sub classes of Circle and Square.
If I was able to print out methods to Circle I would possibly see:

```
.getRadius()
.setRadius(newValue)
```

but Square would have

```
 .getSide()
 .setSide(newValue)
```

I have a myObject, where I know I can get

```
myObject[1].GetLength()
myObject[1].getDimUom()
myObject[1].getQuantity().getValue()
```

However I am unaware of what I can set only certain things like (by trial and error)

```
myObject[1].setClass(newValue)
```

So I would like to be able to find a way to print out the method names from an Object; again without any ability to see or modify base code (like adding reflection)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/method.html

Comment: You mean at compile time? Are you looking for an IDE with suggestions / auto-complete?? E.g. in Eclipse, "myObject."+Ctrl+Space offers you a list of public methods.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically want is to brake the *information hiding* principle which is the most fundamental principle in OOP.

What You (most likely) really want is to define a *common behavior* that could be implemented by the subclasses in their specific way. Regarding your example this could be a method `changeSizeTo(int newValue)` defined in an *interface* that would be implemented by your classes and each class would do something specific.

---

[update]

> I mean anything available to public is it really hiding? – Edward

The point is not about the actual access modifiers but the question: *"Does this force the caller to know what subclass this object actually is?"*

Comment: To the Information hiding, yes and no. I mean anything available to public is it really hiding? Also from what I gather is I am looking for interface names not class method names?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can use reflection.

```
Class clazz = circle.getRadius().getClass();

Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();

for ( Method method : methods ) {
     System.out.println( method.getName() );
}
```

> With that said, you should listen to the advice given by @Timothy Truckle.  You most likely have a design problem if you need to use this, assuming you aren't writing a framework or a library

Comment: I am unsure I have reflection available, I attempted your suggestion but the debug showed me this `
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:18:9 Expected an operand but found ]
  Method[] methods = items[1].getMethods();
         ^ in <eval> at line number 18 at column number 9`

Comment: @Edward Where are you running this? Is it in some type of platform?

Comment: Yes its a third-party platform. And yes I have only been given basic insight into what's available as a customer, and not the full scope; which is why I am trying to find what else is available; which does go to hiding information mentioned by Timothy.

Comment: @Edward and you imported the necessary classes? And you you replaced `circle.getRadius().getClass();` with whatever your object/method is?

Comment: Correct. However I am not sure Method is a defined object, nor do I have faith that reflection is an import in the JAVA script.

Comment: @Edward so just to clarify you added `import java.lang.reflect.Method` at the top of the script?  If that doesn't work in your platform there is really no other solution.  This is only accomplished via reflection.  What is the name of the platform?  Also, I see you have item[1],getMethods().  What is in items[1]?  Is it a Class object or is it an object from Shape?  If it's not an object of type class then your script is wrong.  Please update your original post with what you have now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237853/discussion-between-chris-maggiulli-and-edward).